# Angular: Dynamically setting base href to fix SVG breaks router navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, angular-router

My Angular 7 app works fine if I have `<base href="/">` in the `<head>`

However, this breaks all the SVG gradients in Safari, they render as solid black.  I have found many posts on this issue on SO and elsewhere, and the "solution" is to remove the base tag. But then all my routing and root-relative image srcs break (as expected).

So I looked at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) at `APP_BASE_HREF` and tried the suggested code:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

The images work, but when I build the project with Angular CLI and upload it to AWS, the router links fail after a few clicks (possibly some paths fail?).  No error in console, just no navigation.

So I had to revert to putting the `base` tag in the head, but now my D3 chart gradients are all black in Safari.

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? linear-gradients referenced by url() in an SVG still break in Angular 10 when the router navigates :(

Comment: It would seem this way fixed in a newer version of Safari. We no longer has the problem.

Comment: This is currently happening on the latest version of Chrome, sorry I missed that you were talking specifically about Safari.